# Question about stock volume and stock price

Tags: stocks

I'm looking at this stock's behavior:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BLUE?p=BLUE

If you look at the price chart in full screen mode, on 12/20/2023 it dropped to a closing price of $1.32. The volume was extraordinarily high at 125 million. The very next day the price opens at $1.37.

So I'm a little confused here, because at first glance it seems a ton of people/institutions were selling due to the low price. But if it rose the very next day, does it actually mean this 125 million volume was actually more representative of buying pressure? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the closing price and the next day's opening price is made up of two factors:

1. any overnight or out of hours trading
2. trading during the opening auction which sets the opening price

The price at the end of the auction is the published price and is the most likely to have the highest amount of volume between the close and the opening price print and therefore that volume is what will make the opening price normally. The price on the 20th rose from $1.3100    to  1.3200 (look at the [historical data](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BLUE/history?p=BLUE)) and then rose further to 1.3700 on the open. Implying that there was a general buy consensus over the period from 20th open to 21st close. There was also an intraday drop to $1.2600 (the "low" column) and a spike to a high of $1.4000. It looks like your analysis of the data is flawed at the very least. Intraday peaks and troughs are only really interesting to traders rather than investors and are generally governed by temporary imbalances. Don't read too much into differences in benchmark prices such as open and close in general as they are intended to be a simple view on complex trading.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. People sell when they think they have a better use for the money. That can be because they are concerned about this stock, enthusiastic about another, nervous about the market (or that corner of it) in general... And short-term changes are often just the mood of rhe moment or a statistical hiccup.

The whole concert of "pressure" is questionable except as a general model of how the market tends to behave. I don't think it has a lot of value when trying to understand details.

Comment: When demand for shares (buying) exceeds supply (selling), share price rises.  When the supply of shares exceeds demand, share price drops. Some call this buy and sell pressure.

Comment: I grant that the term is used. I just think it's somewhat misleading, making it sound more mechanical/predictable that it is, especially in detail and  in the short term. It's useful for understanding base mechanisms and general behavior, much less so when looking at individual equities, I think. The quants will probably claim otherwise. And I don't pretend to be an expert; take my opinion, like everyone else's, with the appropriate 5-pound block of salt.

Comment: It's not misleading.  Traders analyze Level 2 quotes which provides more detailed information about current supply and demand (market depth), identifying buying and selling pressure.  Rather than being predictive, it's reactive.  I've never done it but I've observed a couple of traders doing it.  One traded futures, consistently scalping decent money in minutes with minimal exposure risk.

Answer (score 1):

On 12/20/23, they priced 83,333,333 shares of common stock at $1.50 per share.  I suspect that this secondary offering may have been part of the volume spike to 125 million.

Whenever a trade occurs, there's a buyer and a seller.  If price remained unchanged, that means that means that there is equilibrium and there isn't any net buying or selling pressure.

Excess supply (selling) or excess demand (buying) is what causes price to change, not total volume.  Therefore, it's a mistake to assume that a trading volume of 125 million shares is either buying or selling pressure.